# Scala: How to print a list of map using scala

Tags: scala

I am writing below code,

```
val maplist=List(Map("id" -> "1", "Name" -> "divya"), 
         Map("id" -> "2", "Name" -> "gaya")
        )

val header=maplist.flatMap(_.keys).distinct
val data=maplist.flatMap(_.values)
println(header)
println(data)
```

I am getting the below output,

```
List(id, Name)
List(1, divya, 2, gaya)
```

however I am expecting output as below,

id   Name

1    Divya

2    gaya

here in this case I am having only 2 header but in my map it may contain more than 2 headers how to display all in rows. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    val maplist=List(Map("id" -> "1", "Name" -> "divya"),
        Map("id" -> "2", "Name" -> "gaya")
    )

    val header=maplist.flatMap(_.keys).distinct
    val data=maplist.map(_.values)
    println(header.mkString(" "))
    data.foreach(x => println(x.mkString(" ")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, how to convert the same in to data frame instead of printing the output using println. I have to use .show() function to display the output.

Comment: New question, new topic.